# Oracle SQL Developer can't connect to remote database

Tags: oracle, windows-8, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have Windows 8 and Oracle SQL Developer. When I tried to connect to a remote server, it give me v$session.osuser error and vendor code 17190.

Do anyone know what this means? I have tried to search for the vendor code 17190 but nothing related to Oracle.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the username? I think it is exceeding 30 characters or having some characters which are not allowed as a database username. I am not posting it as an answer, as you need to provide more details.

Comment: Forgot to ask first, are you using OS authentication? If yes, then answer my first comment.

Comment: No, I'm using the database user